# Tensorflow dataset group by string key

Tags: python, tensorflow, group-by, hashmap, tensorflow-datasets

I have a tensorflow dataset that I would like to group by key. However, my keys are strings and not integers to I can't do that:

```py
person_tensor = tf.constant(["person1", "person2", "person1", "person3", "person3"])
value_tensor = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((person_tensor, value_tensor)).map(lambda person, value: {'person': person, 'value': value})
# >> list(ds.as_numpy_iterator())
# [{'person': b'person1', 'value': 1},
#  {'person': b'person2', 'value': 2},
#  {'person': b'person1', 'value': 3},
#  {'person': b'person3', 'value': 4},
#  {'person': b'person3', 'value': 5}]

window_size = 10  # not very important, I don't care getting multiple groups for one key as long as there is only one key per group
ds.group_by_window(
    key_func=lambda row: row['person'],
    window_size=window_size,
    reduce_func=lambda key, rows: rows.batch(window_size)
)
# ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int64 for Tensor with dtype string: <tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=() dtype=string>
```

This method complains about string not being able to be converted to int64. Indeed, the `key_func` function is supposed to return an int64 and not a string as I did.

Is there another method to group a dataset by key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try utilizing `tf.lookup.StaticHashTable` like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

person_tensor = tf.constant(["person1", "person2", "person1", "person3", "person3"])
value_tensor = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])

k_tensor = tf.unique(person_tensor)[0]
v_tensor = tf.cast(tf.range(tf.shape(k_tensor)[0]), dtype=tf.int64)
table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(k_tensor, v_tensor),
    default_value=-1)

reverse_table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(v_tensor, k_tensor),
    default_value="")

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((person_tensor, value_tensor)).map(lambda person, value: {'person': table.lookup(person), 'value': value})

window_size = 10  # not very important, I don't care getting multiple groups for one key as long as there is only one key per group
ds = ds.group_by_window(
    key_func=lambda row: row['person'],
    window_size=window_size,
    reduce_func=lambda key, rows: rows.batch(window_size)
)
ds = ds.map(lambda d: {'person': tf.unique(reverse_table.lookup(d['person']))[0], 'value': d['value']})
list(ds.as_numpy_iterator())
```

```
[{'person': array([b'person1'], dtype=object),
  'value': array([1, 3], dtype=int32)},
 {'person': array([b'person2'], dtype=object),
  'value': array([2], dtype=int32)},
 {'person': array([b'person3'], dtype=object),
  'value': array([4, 5], dtype=int32)}]
```

Or if you really have some unique number in your strings, you could also try using `tf.strings.bytes_split` and `tf.strings.to_number`:

```
person_tensor = tf.constant(["person1", "person2", "person1", "person3", "person3"])
value_tensor = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((person_tensor, value_tensor)).map(lambda person, value: {'person': person, 'value': value})
window_size = 10  # not very important, I don't care getting multiple groups for one key as long as there is only one key per group
ds = ds.group_by_window(
    key_func=lambda row: tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.bytes_split(row['person'])[-1], tf.int64),
    window_size=window_size,
    reduce_func=lambda key, rows: rows.batch(window_size)
)
ds = ds.map(lambda d: {'person': tf.unique(d['person'])[0], 'value': d['value']})

list(ds.as_numpy_iterator())
```

```
[{'person': array([b'person1'], dtype=object),
  'value': array([1, 3], dtype=int32)},
 {'person': array([b'person2'], dtype=object),
  'value': array([2], dtype=int32)},
 {'person': array([b'person3'], dtype=object),
  'value': array([4, 5], dtype=int32)}]
```

Or you could try using `tf.strings.to_hash_bucket_fast`:

```
person_tensor = tf.constant(["person1", "person2", "person1", "person3", "person3"])
value_tensor = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((person_tensor, value_tensor)).map(lambda person, value: {'person': person, 'value': value})
window_size = 10  # not very important, I don't care getting multiple groups for one key as long as there is only one key per group
ds = ds.group_by_window(
    key_func=lambda row: tf.strings.to_hash_bucket_fast(row['person'], 5),
    window_size=window_size,
    reduce_func=lambda key, rows: rows.batch(window_size)
)
ds = ds.map(lambda d: {'person': tf.unique(d['person'])[0], 'value': d['value']})

list(ds.as_numpy_iterator())
```

```
[{'person': array([b'person3'], dtype=object),
  'value': array([4, 5], dtype=int32)},
 {'person': array([b'person1'], dtype=object),
  'value': array([1, 3], dtype=int32)},
 {'person': array([b'person2'], dtype=object),
  'value': array([2], dtype=int32)}]
```

Comment: Ideally, I would like to avoid creating a lookup table because I have *a lot* of data, and I would like to avoid having to pass over it twice as I would be quite long. It could even be a problem if all my keys do not fit in memory (therefore I wouldn't be able to create the `k_tensor`).

Comment: See other solutions @leleogere

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not necessarily have a unique number in my strings. I guess the hash solution is the way to go even if it could lead to collisions. Thank you!

Comment: The main problem with this method is that with 2^63-1 buckets (max value if int64) and 500M different strings, the probability of collision is around 1%. I wish tensorflow datasets could natively be grouped by string like other libraries allow (pandas, pyspark...)

Comment: Yeah it is definitely a drawback with this approach.